# I have to figure out if the numbers in an array are factors of a given number

Tags: java

Ex:

- areFactors( [3,4,6], 12 ) --> true
- areFactors( [2,4,6], 10 ) --> false
- areFactors( [], 6 )       --> false

```
public static boolean areFactors(int[] arrNum, int n){

   if (arrNum == null || arrNum.length == 0){
     return false;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++){
     if (n % arrNum[i] == 0){
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

There are a few tests that won't pass and I also get division by zero exception.

Comment: You are returning `true` the first time you find a divisor of `n`. This is wrong. You need to check all elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array contains any 0s, you should return false.

Other than that, you should return `false` when you encounter a number that is not a factor of `n`.

Return `true` only after the loop (i.e. after validating that all the array elements are factors of `n`).

```
public static boolean areFactors (int[] arrNum, int n) {

   if (arrNum == null || arrNum.length == 0) {
     return false;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
     if (arrNum[i] == 0 || n % arrNum[i] != 0) {
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code.

Here you can find a solution what you are going to achieve:

```
public static boolean areFactors(int[] arrNum, int n) {
    if (arrNum == null || arrNum.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
        int num = arrNum[i];
        if (num != 0 && n % num != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your fixes and you missed the null pointer check.

Comment: @Milgo null pointer check is done on the first line.

Comment: What if arrNum contains 0?

Comment: @Milgo this is an edge case. It has nothing with Null pointer check. This check depends on the task and input. However, the main obstacle is been already overcome.

Comment: You missed an arithmetic exception: / by zero

Comment: @BUG fixed this case.